# Can't send email from my Centos server

Tags: php, linux, email, centos, redhat

My server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 .
I am trying to send simple emails using localhost.

```
$to = 'kosala@xxxxxx.com;
    $subject = 'Fake sendmail test';
    $message = 'If we can read this, it means that our fake Sendmail setup works!';
    $headers = 'From: myemail@egmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: myemail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'Email sent successfully!';
    } else {
        die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
    }
```

response is : **Email sent successfully!**

But i have not received any mails.My smtp port 25 is open,i checked it using below command.

> nmap -sT -O localhost

Output of `echo "test" | sendmail xxxx@gmail.com` command is

> You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root

Thanks in advance, Kosala

Comment: Is it not in spam? Try sending it to a different provider - gmail might be blocking these kind of things. You should really be using a proper mail sending service provider to send emails if you do not want to end up with emails in the spam box.

Comment: Please check first manual whether your mail service is working properly or not. To check that use this command from your console:- echo "test" | sendmail yourmail@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks your valuable helps. It is not inside spam box.After i execute echo "test" | sendmail yourmail@gmail.com command output was You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root. @Hemdip

Comment: Yea its correct but did you get email in your inbox by using that command?

Comment: I did not get. any mails. @Hemdip

Comment: Please check your mail delivery status using this command :-  tail -f /var/log/mail.log

Comment: I used `tail -f /var/log/maillog` command to view the log. then i saw **stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com** for gmail addresses and **stat=Sent** for other email addresses. but i did not receive the email @Hemdip

Comment: @John Conde .This is a configuration problem of redhat  not a simple php problem. I can sent mail in my UAT server.

Comment: I found the problem ."As of October 28th, 2015, SoftLayer no longer allows outbound connections through TCP port 25 (SMTP) on new accounts."   (http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/content/outbound-email-port-25) @John Conde